# Issue while adding Android TV release type

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, android-tv

I am facing an issue while adding Android TV option in release type from Google Play Console Advance settings. For the first time when I submitted the release type by adding TV screenshots and checking Opt-in option, at that time I've got the status as "In review" but almost after a day they've mailed me this:
[Screenshot of mail received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOVz5.jpg)

But now whenever I submit new TV-app release and try to submit the release type with checking Opt-in option again, it showing "Update rejected" every-time without being reviewed.
[Screenshot of release type status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXyJM.jpg)

Please help!